# What's involved with using Salesforce as a client to a WCF service that has a DataContract that contains classes that inherit from a base class?

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance, apex

WCF does not generate any overridden properties - they just don't show up in the WSDL.
And Salesforce doesn't recognize inheritance when it imports a WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

I created a base class (Base) that included common columns (properties) for some tables I was querying.  The column names were the same except for a two character prefix:

- PDSTATUS
- PCSTATUS
- PHSTATUS

These 3 became Status in the Base class with [Column(Name = "STATUS")] attribute and the prefix stored in the derived class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

public class Class1
{
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Contract))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Product))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Customer))]
    public abstract class Base
    {
        protected virtual string _sourcePrefix { get; private set; }

        //[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)] // Doesn't seem to do anything
        [IgnoreDataMember] // Only way I could get this to not show up in the WSDL for Base class
        public virtual string Id { get; protected set; }

        [Column(Name = "PRCNGID")] // This is the key for Contracts, foreign key for Customers and Products
        [IgnoreDataMember] // I don't want this to show up in the Base class in the WSDL, only for Contract
        public virtual string ContractId { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "EFFDT")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "EXPDT")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "STATUS")]
        [DataMember]
        public Statuses Status { get; set; }
    }

    [Table(Name = "PRPCN10C")]
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Base))]
    public class Contract : Base
    {
        protected override string _sourcePrefix { get { return "PC"; } }

        //[IgnoreDataMember] // Using ContractId field instead for this class' Id
        //public override string Id
        //{
        //    get { return base.Id; }
        //    protected set { base.Id = value; }
        //}

        [Column(Name = "PRCNGID")]
        [DataMember]
        public new string ContractId
        {
            get { return base.ContractId; }
            set { base.ContractId = value; }
        }

        [Column(Name = "PRCNGTYP")]
        [DataMember]
        public Types ContractType { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "NAME")]
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "ROOTCT#")]
        [DataMember]
        public string RootContractNumber { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "CMTTYP")]
        [DataMember]
        public string CommitmentType { get; set; }
    }

    [Table(Name = "PRPCN30H")]
    [DataContract]
    public class Customer : Base
    {
        protected override string _sourcePrefix { get { return "PH"; } }

        [Column(Name = "SHPTO#")]
        [DataMember(Name = "CustomerNumber")]
        public new string Id
        {
            get { return base.Id; }
            protected set { base.Id = value; }
        }
    }

    [Table(Name = "PRPCN20D")]
    [DataContract]
    public class Product : Base
    {
        protected override string _sourcePrefix { get { return "PD"; } }

        [Column(Name = "ITEM")]
        [DataMember(Name = "ProductNumber")]
        public new string Id
        {
            get { return base.Id; }
            protected set { base.Id = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I added the Table and Column attributes so I could use Reflection to build the query against the source database and process the results from the DataReader returned from my OleDb ExecuteReader.

I had originally tried declaring the properties in the derived classes using override like this:

```
        [Column(Name = "ITEM")]
        [DataMember(Name = "ProductNumber")]
        public new string Id
        {
            get { return base.Id; }
            protected set { base.Id = value; }
        }
```

But WCF didn't seem to know what to do with it.  Instead of generating properties for the derived classes, it only generated a property in the base class and ignored the new DataMember Name.

So - now that I figured out the WCF part, I opened the ?singleWSDL generated on my server and imported it into Salesforce using the wsdl2apex utility (Generate from WSDL button on the Apex Classes page).

I had to remove any xs:attribute elements (wsdl2apex doesn't like them), and after I did that, it generated 3 Apex classes:
1) the Serialization properties (it was basically empty for this)
2) the Class definitions: Base, Contract, Customer, Product
3) the classes & methods used by the web callout in Salesforce

The resulting class definition file contained this:

```
    //Generated by wsdl2apex

    public class CPQ_PricingContractWSClasses {
        public class PricingContract {
            public CPQ_PricingContractWSClasses.ArrayOfPricingContract_Contract Contracts;
            public CPQ_PricingContractWSClasses.ArrayOfPricingContract_Customer Customers;
            public CPQ_PricingContractWSClasses.ArrayOfPricingContract_Product Products;
            private String[] Contracts_type_info = new String[]{'Contracts','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] Customers_type_info = new String[]{'Customers','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] Products_type_info = new String[]{'Products','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'Contracts','Customers','Products'};
        }
        public class ArrayOfPricingContract_Contract {
            public CPQ_PricingContractWSClasses.PricingContract_Contract[] PricingContract_Contract;
            private String[] PricingContract_Contract_type_info = new String[]{'PricingContract.Contract','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','-1','true'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'PricingContract_Contract'};
        }
        public class ArrayOfPricingContract_Customer {
            public CPQ_PricingContractWSClasses.PricingContract_Customer[] PricingContract_Customer;
            private String[] PricingContract_Customer_type_info = new String[]{'PricingContract.Customer','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','-1','true'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'PricingContract_Customer'};
        }
        public virtual class PricingContract_Customer {
            public String CustomerNumber;
            private String[] CustomerNumber_type_info = new String[]{'CustomerNumber','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'CustomerNumber'};
        }
        public virtual class PricingContract_Product {
            public String ProductNumber;
            private String[] ProductNumber_type_info = new String[]{'ProductNumber','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'ProductNumber'};
        }
        public virtual class PricingContract_Contract {
            public String CommitmentType;
            public String ContractType;
            public String Name;
            public String RootContractNumber;
            public String ContractId;
            private String[] CommitmentType_type_info = new String[]{'CommitmentType','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] ContractType_type_info = new String[]{'ContractType','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','false'};
            private String[] Name_type_info = new String[]{'Name','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] RootContractNumber_type_info = new String[]{'RootContractNumber','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'CommitmentType','ContractType','Name','RootContractNumber'};
        }
        public virtual class PricingContract_Base {
            public DateTime EffectiveDate;
            public DateTime ExpirationDate;
            public String Status;
            private String[] EffectiveDate_type_info = new String[]{'EffectiveDate','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] ExpirationDate_type_info = new String[]{'ExpirationDate','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] Status_type_info = new String[]{'Status','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','false'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'EffectiveDate','ExpirationDate','Status'};
        }
        public class ArrayOfPricingContract_Product {
            public CPQ_PricingContractWSClasses.PricingContract_Product[] PricingContract_Product;
            private String[] PricingContract_Product_type_info = new String[]{'PricingContract.Product','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','-1','true'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'PricingContract_Product'};
        }
    }
```

It looks close, but nothing is declared virtual, there is no Extends, etc.

If you try to use the classes/properties in your code, you will get an error like this:

Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element EffectiveDate

Saleforce support says inheritence is not supported in the web callout, so I had to get around it by doing a copy/paste of all the properties and _type_info fields from the Base class into each derived class.  I also had to update the field_order_type_info field and add the properties I copied from the Base class.  Here's an example of one class after modification:

```
        public virtual class PricingContract_Product {
            public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
            public String ProductNumber { get; set; }
            public String Status { get; set; }
            private String[] EffectiveDate_type_info = new String[]{'EffectiveDate','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] ExpirationDate_type_info = new String[]{'ExpirationDate','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] ProductNumber_type_info = new String[]{'ProductNumber','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','true'};
            private String[] Status_type_info = new String[]{'Status','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract',null,'0','1','false'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SFDC.Services.DataContract','true','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'EffectiveDate','ExpirationDate','ProductNumber','Status'};
        }
```

I was accessing these classes and properties from Visualfource pages, so I had to add { get; } to all properties so VF would see them.  I also manually added the virtual because I wanted to extend the class in my other code.